# problems triggering functions when scroll back to top of webpage

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, jquery-animate

I am working on a fixed position top nav bar that "appears" after the visitor starts scrolling.  (Appears as in the background changes, logo resizes and borders appear so that it looks separate from the rest of the webpage, the nav links themselves are already visible at the page's top).

The appears part is pretty easy using jQuery's scroll() and animate().

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
     $('.logo img').animate({"height": "65px"}, 500);
     $('#header').css({"border": "1px solid #999", "padding-top": "1px"});
 });
```

But the part that is stumping me is undoing the changes when the visitor scrolls back to the top, so that the nav bar blends back into the webpage.

I added a position function which seemed to work pretty well ... BUT ... the img resizing is delayed upon return to the top, sometimes by as much as a minute or two.  The border and padding changes take effect immediately upon return to the top, only the img resizing is delayed.

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
     if ($(this).scrollTop()>0) {
          $('.logo img').animate({"height": "65px"}, 300);
          $('#header').css({"border": "1px solid #999", "padding-top": "1px"});
     } else {
          $('.logo img').animate({"height": "114px"}, 300);
          $('#header').css({"border": "1px solid #fff", "padding-top": "8px"})
     }
 });
```

If I change both of the img functions to css() it works, but I lose the smooth shrinking of the image that animate provides.

Any suggestions from the experts out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding .stop() behind the animate function

```
$('.logo img').stop().animate({"height": "65px"}, 300);
```

Comment: Or, use `.stop(true, true)`

Comment: Thanks that seems to the trick.  I figured there had to be something simple, but as I only work on one website I don't have a lot of experience with jQuery.

Comment: The stop(true, true) seems to disable the animate function, whereas the stop() doesn't.